# AngularJS: app.js (RouteProvider) throwing an "Uncaught Object"

Tags: angularjs

I think I have narrowed my problem to the $routeProvider because I had 24 routes and was getting the "Uncaught Object" error 24 times and I reduced it to 1 route and not have only 1 "Uncaught Object." The error message doesn't give any more info that its name.

This is my app.js:

```
var appARM = angular.module('appARM', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils']);

appARM.config(function($routeProvider){
   $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
          controller: 'MainController',
          templateUrl: '/ang/views/landing.html'
      }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

Does anyone see anything that would cause an "Uncaught Object" error?

Thanks in advance!

~~~UPDATE~~~
This is the angular master page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="appARM">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>XXXX</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Jonathan Gravois">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Meta -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/appng.css"/>

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ui-bootstrap-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ui-utils.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/controllers/mainApp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/controllers/newApp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/controllers/editApp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/controllers/users.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/controllers/farmers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/controllers/locations.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/services/usersFactory.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/services/applicationsFactory.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ang/services/appFilters.js"></script>
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-160x160.png" sizes="160x160">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div data-ng-controller="MainController">
            <div id="full_page">
                <div id="main_container" style="min-height:800px;">
                    <div data-ng-include="'ang/views/partials/logobar.html'"></div>
                    <div data-ng-view></div>
                </div> <!-- end #main_container -->
            </div> <!-- end #full_page -->
        </div> <!-- end #main_container -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you include `ng-route` script?

Comment: yes, (AngularJS v1.2.16) I updated my question to show my master page

Comment: try removing the function that is wrapping your angular. you shouldn't need it.

Comment: I removed the SIAF and still get the error ... without that, isn't everything being dumped into the global?

Comment: next step is to remove all javascript references from your html except angular and angular-route.

Comment: I removed all references except main.js and the error persisted. I removed the call to main.js and removed it and replaced the controller and templateUrl in the route with a plain template and the error persisted.

Comment: Grap a breakpoint where Angular throws the error (in the angular source), there you can inspect the error which should make more sense, I have had to do that for providers and config blocks as of late.

Comment: it throws at 1611 -- return ensure(modules, name, function() {
        if (!requires) {
          throw $injectorMinErr('nomod', "Module '{0}' is not available! You either misspelled " +
             "the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you " +
             "specify the dependencies as the second argument.", name);
        }